# Can numPos be a Negative Number in Haar Cascade Training

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I am trying my own haar cascade classifier I have 2139 positive images However I have 16000 negative images This is right ? And so I have a negative numPos 
Because:
 numPos<=(Positive samples-negative samples)/(1+(stages number-1)*(1-minhitrate)))
 so:
  (2139-16000)/(1+(17-1)*(1-0.995))=-12834 
 This is normal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, numPos has nothing to do with your negative samples. numPos is the number of positives you want to use in each stage. This must be a bit lower than your total number of positive samples because you'll lose all the false negatives ( = positive samples which are falsely not detected anymore by the classifier)  in each stage.

For example if you sr numPos to 1000 and minHitRate to 0.999 you lose up to 1 positive sample (1000 - 1000*0.999) in each stage. So if you want to compute 2 stages you'll need up to 1001 samples when choosing numPos = 1000.

For 20 stages I roughly choose numPos to be 90% of my positive samples although that is too pessimistic for minHitRate 0.999 (fits 0.995 quite well afair). There is a formula in the openCV Q&A if you want to compute the best/max save value.

Comment: Thank you somuch And I have more negative images than positive images (positive images are 2139 However negative images are 16000 is this a problem?)

Comment: no, this isn't a problem. The more negatives the better (imho). But choose numNeg not too big, Remember that typically 50% of your negatives are lost inneach stage. But negatives are subsampled so typically you'll have plenty of them. Have a look at the acceptanceRatio in each stage to understand why later stages need so much time to find enough negative samples. I typically choose numNeg about 2*numPos.

Comment: Thank you again  :)

Comment: hmm I choosed negative images number for numNeg number Is this a problem :(?

Comment: you might run out of negatives soon, but maybe not. Try it :)

Comment: Ok I am trying now :)

Comment: You wanted to say minHitRate or MaxFalseAlarmRate ??

Comment: yea, minHitRate